# Hopefully simple multivariable differential equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a system of differential equations of a similar form and it seems like it should be easy, but I just don't know how to reduce it. Basically, for an arbitrary n values, I need to solve:

$\large{\Large{\frac{dc_i}{dt}}\large = m_ix_i + b_i \\
x_i = c_i + \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j}$

If the $m_ix_i$ term is removed it becomes trivial as it can be solved linearly in a matrix or otherwise. And in a vacuum without the other summation the function becomes a simple equation to solve for each x, but I can't seem to make the derivatives become any simpler. How do I even start on the problem?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\totald{c_{i}}{t} = m_{i}x_{i} + b_{i}\,,\quad
x_i = c_i + \sum_{j}^{n}a_{ij}x_{j}}$

> With obvious definitions for the vectors ${\bf c}$, ${\bf x}$ and
> ${\bf b}$ and for the matrices $M$ and $A$; those equations are equivalent to the pair of vectorial equations:
> \begin{align}
> \totald{\bf c}{t} = M{\bf x} + {\bf b}\quad\mbox{and}\quad
> {\bf x} = {\bf c} + A{\bf x}
> \end{align}

From the second equation, ${\bf x} = \pars{1 - A}^{-1}{\bf c}$ where we assumed that $\pars{1 - A}$ is not a singular matrix. Then, we get:
$$
\pars{\totald{}{t} - B}{\bf c} = {\bf b}\quad\mbox{where}\quad
B \equiv M\pars{1 - A}^{-1}\quad\imp\quad
\totald{\pars{\expo{-Bt}{\bf c}}}{t} = \expo{-Bt}{\bf b}
$$
$$
\expo{-Bt}{\bf c}\pars{t} - \expo{-Bt_{0}}{\bf c}\pars{t_{0}}
=
\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\expo{-Bt'}{\bf b}\,\dd t'\quad\imp\quad
{\bf c}\pars{t}
= \expo{B\pars{t - t_{0}}}{\bf c}\pars{t_{0}}
+
\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\expo{-B\pars{t' - t}}{\bf b}\,\dd t'
$$

> $$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
> \begin{array}{rcl}
> {\bf c}\pars{t}
> & = &
> \expo{B\pars{t - t_{0}}}{\bf c}\pars{t_{0}}
> +
> \pars{\int_{0}^{t - t_{0}}\expo{Bt'}\,\dd t'}{\bf b}
> \\
> B & \equiv & M\pars{1 - A}^{-1}
> \quad\mbox{where}\ \pars{1 - A}\ \mbox{is not a singular matrix.}
> \end{array}}
> $$

Comment: I'm sorry but this isn't what I intended at all. Matrices are not involved, and the x term is entirely separate from the one on the left, hence why it had its own summation in terms of j, and why it was $a_{i,j}$ instead of just a or something like you had here. Because for each x in the set it is equal to a specific value plus some multiple of all the previous ones

Comment: I guess you have to rewrite the sum term $\large\sum_{j}^{n}$. Otherwise, it's confused.

Comment: Not sure what more you want. I don't have any real numeric bounds. It's just a summation in terms of j up to n. And why would I even have j in the first place if it was equal to i, or the summation, or anything other than the 1 - a already there.

Comment: Then, write $\large\sum_{\color{#ff0000}{j = i - 1}}^{n}\ldots$. Otherwise, nobody can guess that feature. Any way, we can always write $\large\sum_{\color{#ff0000}{j = 1}}^{n}$ provided $\large a_{ij} = 0$ for $\large j \geq i$.

Comment: It includes j <= i and j >= i, and saying j = 0 or j = 1 gives literally no information over that. It's literally exactly what it is iterating over all possible values. If you can always write it there's no point in writing it.